# If Statements in While Loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am currently trying to make a program that opens, closes, turns on, and turns off a "Dishwasher". When I run this program once, i get my intended result of:

```
Welcome to SiriWash
What would you like to do?
Open Door | Close Door | Turn on | Turn Off 
open door
opening door
The Dishwasher is Open and Off
What would you like to do?
Open Door | Close Door | Turn on | Turn Off
```

Thouugh if I do this again, I get:

```
Welcome to SiriWash
What would you like to do?
Open Door | Close Door | Turn on | Turn Off 
open door
opening door
The Dishwasher is Open and Off
What would you like to do?
Open Door | Close Door | Turn on | Turn Off 
close door
What would you like to do?
Open Door | Close Door | Turn on | Turn Off
```

Here is the Runner Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean gameRunning = true;
        Dishwasher washer1 = new Dishwasher(false,false);
        washer1.open();
        washer1.turnOff();
        //System.out.println(washer1);
        System.out.println("Welcome to SiriWash");
        String answer = "";
        //String answer = "";
        while (gameRunning) {
            System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
            System.out.println("Open Door | Close Door | Turn on | Turn Off ");
            answer = reader.nextLine();
            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("open door")) {
                washer1.open();
                System.out.println("opening door");
                System.out.println(washer1);
                answer = "";
            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("close door")) {
                washer1.close();
                System.out.println("Closing door");
                System.out.println(washer1);
                answer = "";
            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("turn on")) {
                washer1.turnOn();
                System.out.println("turning on");
                System.out.println(washer1);
                answer = "";
            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("turn off")){
                washer1.turnOff();
                System.out.println("turning off");
                System.out.println(washer1);
                answer = "";
            }
            }
            }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

It would seem that the if statements are skipped during a second input, how would I fix this?

Comment: Use System.out.println to see which value the answer variable actually holds before you arrive at your if statements. I have a suspicion that  it doesn't hold the value you think it does after the first loop.

Comment: Just checked, It does hold the new variable, at least when I have it print out the variable right before the first if statement.

Comment: The problem i think is that the toString is not printing on the second loop of the while loop, and neither is the "opening door" String

Answer (score 0):

All your `if`s are nested so if the first fails, all the rest are skipped. Try closing the curly braces after each `if` body as:

```
if( condition1 ){
    body
}
if( condition2 ){
    body2
}
...
```

Comment: The principal problem I saw were the curly braces, that's why I posted this solution. Of course, it is a better practice to use `else if` if the coditions are mutually exclusive. I'm glad you solved your problem.